# C# - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to retrieving data from a collection as follow

```
var results = await repository.FindAsync(GetFilter(ids));

private System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<SomeEntity, bool>> GetFilter(IEnumerable<long> someIds)
{
    return x => someIds.Contains(x.Id) &&
                x.subscriptions
               .Where(s => s.servicePlans.Contains((int)ServicePlanEnum.Service1)).Any();
}
```

but I got the following exception

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:

Subscription object looks like:

```
subscription :
{
    prop1 : string,
    prop2 : int,
    servicePlans : int[]
}
```

FindAsync definition:

```
protected IMongoCollection<TEntity> Collection => database.GetCollection<TEntity>(collectionName);
private IFindFluent<TEntity, TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) => Collection.Find(predicate);
public virtual async Task<ICollection<TEntity>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, SortOrder<TEntity>[] sort = null, int? page = null, int? limit = null)
{
    var query = Find(predicate);

    return await
        query
            .Skip(page == null && limit == null ? null : (page - 1) * limit)
            .Limit(limit)
            .Sort(sort)
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

The error is caused by the following condition

```
x.subscriptions.Where(s => s.servicePlans.Contains((int)ServicePlanEnum.Service1)).Any();
```

EDIT:

stacktrace:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionHelper.GetLambda(Expression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.MethodCallBinders.AnyBinder.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, EmbeddedPipelineBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.MethodInfoMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.CompositeMethodCallBinder`1.Bind(PipelineExpression pipeline, TBindingContext bindingContext, MethodCallExpression node, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.PipelineBinderBase`1.BindMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.EmbeddedPipeline.EmbeddedPipelineBinder.Bind(Expression node, IBindingContext parent)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Processors.SerializationBinder.Visit(Expression node)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindAsync[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass43_0`1.b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToListAsync[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at ...Repository.MongoRepository`2.FindAsync(Expression`1 predicate, SortOrder`1[] sort, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 limit) in ...\Infastructure\Repositories\MongoRepository.cs:line 71
>      at ...Controllers.AccountController.GetCliniciansByClinicAsync(String clinicId, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in ...\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 94
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()

Comment: Don't do the cast in the expression store this in a variable (int)SomeEnum.Member

Comment: What is the argument type in `FindAsync()`?

Comment: @johnny5 I didn't understand what you said, (int)SomeEnum.Member is a constant (enum).

Comment: @vendettamit the argument type is the same as the returned type of GetFilter()

Comment: Is this the line where you getting the error? Can you post the complete signature of `FindAsync()`?

Comment: @vendettamit I have edited my answer

Comment: I don't know why your code is failing offhand, but I note that you typically do not have to call `Where(predicate).Any()`. You can usually just call `Any(predicate)`.

Comment: A stack trace would help. Looks like some exception in the MongoDB query provider.

Comment: I suspect that Gert Arnold is correct. Offhand I would not expect that exception from user code like what you've written. My guess would be that most likely, there is some plebbery in the query rewriter. Or, it is possible that the defect is in the expression tree generation itself, which, uh, would make it my fault. But I would start with a call stack and see exactly where things are going bad.

Comment: (If it's not 100% clear to you what "plebbery" is, a web search for "MongoDB plebbery" is a fun way to waste a little time while compiling. This was brought to my attention when I worked at Coverity.)

Comment: I have added the stack trace. I think I figured out the problem. That predicate was being true for two entities in some cases, maybe that's why it blew up. I changed the list of Ids and it's working fine.

Comment: @renatogbp did that resolve this question?

Answer (score 2):

As johnny 5 stated Mongo's C# expression parser is fairly limited.  Another thing to point out is you cannot use method groups those will yield a ConstantExpression similar to your example.  The key is just leaving the full predicate expression.

Bad

```
var list = _collection.Find(r => r.Scopes.Any(scopeNames.Contains)).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Good

```
var list = _collection.Find(r => r.Scopes.Any(s => scopeNames.Contains(s)).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

In the event you have ReSharper or Rider you can disable the code suggestion by putting this comment line right above your code

```
// ReSharper disable once ConvertClosureToMethodGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven’t used the linq to Mongodb but it looks like you’re adding unnecessary complexities to your expression.

When you pass an expression, the code needs to be translated to a query in which mongo can handle.

Contains expects an int, in normal c# this is fine.

But as an expression an int is a constant, but you’ve provided an complex expression. 
e.g casting an enum to an int.  Which is a convert expression.

It seems mongodb expression parser is not advanced enough to handle that.  So let c# do the cast and pass it directly

```
var results = await repository.FindAsync(GetFilter(ids));

private System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<SomeEntity, bool>> GetFilter(IEnumerable<long> someIds)
{
    var serviceVal = (int)ServicePlanEnum.Service1;
    return x => someIds.Contains(x.Id) &&
            x.subscriptions
           .Where(s => s.servicePlans.Contains( serviceVal ).Any();
}
```